# show message while all promises are resolved

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I have a many request ajax, and all those end, show message: "promises ended", but I want show message while: "Processing" or "Working..." and I do not know. I use jquery

```
$("#btnDelete").click(function () {
    var promises = [];
    if (confirm("¿Seguro que quiere borrar?")) {
        $('.delete:checked').each(function (index, value) {
            promesas.push(
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "transaccion.php",
                    data: {
                        id_pagos_detalle: $(this).val(),
                        accion: "Registrar_inf_consignacion",
                        estado_elemento: "Si"
                    }
                }).then(function (msg) {
                    if(msg.indexOf("SUCCESS") != -1){
                        console.log("delete this element");
                    }else{
                        alert("ERROR");
                        return false;
                    }
                })
            );  // end promise  
        });

        // process all promises
        $.when.apply($, promises).then(function(){
            alert("Promises ended");
            location.reload(true);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: show the "Working" message just before `$('.delete:checked').each` - but don't use `alert` - because that is blocking

Answer (score 0):

Jaromanda X is right. You can probably do something like this:

```
$("#btnDelete").click(function () {
var promises = [];
if (confirm("¿Seguro que quiere borrar?")) {

   //Loading message here

    $('#you_div').html('Loading...');
    $('.delete:checked').each(function (index, value) {
        promesas.push(
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "transaccion.php",
                data: {
                    id_pagos_detalle: $(this).val(),
                    accion: "Registrar_inf_consignacion",
                    estado_elemento: "Si"
                }
            }).then(function (msg) {
                if(msg.indexOf("SUCCESS") != -1){

                      //hide the loading message
                      $('#you_div').hide();

                    console.log("delete this element");
                }else{
                    alert("ERROR");
                    return false;
                }
            })
        );  // end promise  
    });

    // process all promises
    $.when.apply($, promises).then(function(){



        alert("Promises ended");
        location.reload(true);
    });
}
});
```

Remember to add you_div to the appropriate place in your html

Comment: Presumably `promesas.push(...)` (as in the question) should be `promises.push(...)`.